# Apache airflow issue while running airflow helm chart 8.7.0 and web server in not running it is stuck on worker exit and restarting

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

`I am using airflow 8.7.0 helm chart and up airflow pods but the web server pod is restarting after giving worker exit error and Received signal: 15. Closing gunicorn.

Error Logs

```
[2023-07-10 05:42:16,665] {providers_manager.py:235} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
      [2023-07-10 05:42:18 +0000] [113] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
      [2023-07-10 05:42:19,182] {providers_manager.py:235} INFO - Optional provider feature disabled when importing 'airflow.providers.google.leveldb.hooks.leveldb.LevelDBHook' from 'apache-airflow-providers-google' package
      [2023-07-10 05:42:19 +0000] [113] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080 (113)
      [2023-07-10 05:42:19 +0000] [113] [INFO] Using worker: sync
      [2023-07-10 05:42:19 +0000] [222] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 222
      [2023-07-10 05:42:19 +0000] [223] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 223
      [2023-07-10 05:42:19 +0000] [224] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 224
      [2023-07-10 05:42:19 +0000] [225] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 225
      [2023-07-10 05:42:49 +0000] [223] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 223)
      [2023-07-10 05:42:49 +0000] [225] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 225)
      [2023-07-10 05:42:49 +0000] [224] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 224)
      [2023-07-10 05:42:49 +0000] [222] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 222)
      [2023-07-10 05:42:49 +0000] [113] [INFO] Handling signal: term
        ____________       _____________
       ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
      ____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
      ___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
       _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/
      Running the Gunicorn Server with:
      Workers: 4 sync
      Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
      Timeout: 120
      Logfiles: - -
      Access Logformat: 
      =================================================================
      [2023-07-10 05:42:49,382] {webserver_command.py:432} INFO - Received signal: 15. Closing gunicorn.
      [2023-07-10 05:42:51 +0000] [113] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

Answer (score 0):

Signal 15 is a SIGTERM. Perhaps your webserver is running out of resources trying to stand up. I solved this issue by increasing the resources for Airflow webserver to

```
cpu: 500m
memory: 4Gi
```